# Video Capture Set Parameter Range?

Tags: opencv, parameters, camera, webcam

I need to use a few of the VideoCapture::set() options for openCV. They are here;

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set

But I cannot find anywhere something that specifies the range of values that can be used to give each parameter a value.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

**That information is really missing**, and with some of them you really need to take a *hit & miss* approach.

For the time being, you can check the return of [`VideoCapture::set()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=videocapture#videocapture-set) to see if the method succeeded in setting that parameter.

Comment: ugh, thanks for the reply then anyway! do you happen to have any experience with brightness and exposure settings?? I have my contrast at 500 (although look the same as 1!!) so looks like they might default to a max vale of if you go over it

Comment: I believe brightness and exposure values must stay between 0-100, but I might be wrong.

Comment: ok thank you karl, will try in the lab tomorrow and let you know!